Getting Error in Grid DB cluster deployment
I tried to deploy a gridDB cluster using a node-based architecture where nodes have some roles. But I am encountering an error.
I tried this:
import subprocess

def start_griddb_server(node):
    command = ['griddb', 'start', '-u', 'admin/admin', '-w', node['name']]
    try:
        subprocess.run(command, check=True)
        print(f"GridDB server started on {node['name']}")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        raise RuntimeError(f"Failed to start GridDB server on {node['name']}: {e}")

def configure_node_roles(nodes):
    for node in nodes:
        command = ['griddb', 'set-role', '-u', 'admin/admin', '-w', node['name'], node['role']]
        try:
            subprocess.run(command, check=True)
            print(f"Node role set for {node['name']}: {node['role']}")
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            raise RuntimeError(f"Failed to set node role for {node['name']}: {e}")

def deploy_griddb_cluster(nodes):
    try:
        for node in nodes:
            start_griddb_server(node)
        
        configure_node_roles(nodes)

        print('GridDB cluster deployment completed successfully.')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error encountered during GridDB cluster deployment: {e}")

deploy_griddb_cluster(nodes)


I am facing error as follow:
Error encountered during GridDB cluster deployment: RuntimeError: Failed to set node role for coordinator: Command 'griddb set-role -u admin/admin -w coordinator COORDINATOR' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Also, I would like to know how to handle case when there is some node's key value is missing to avoid data inconsistency.
